# ASCII Representation of Hexadecimal

Tags: lua, hex, type-conversion, ascii

I have a string that, by using `string.format("%02X", char)`, I've received the following:

`74657874000000EDD37001000300`

In the end, I'd like that string to look like the following:

`t e x t NUL NUL NUL í Ó p SOH NUL ETX NUL`  (spaces are there just for clarification of characters desired in example).

I've tried to use `\x..(hex#)`, `string.char(0x..(hex#))` (where `(hex#)` is alphanumeric representation of my desired character) and I am still having issues with getting the result I'm looking for.  After reading another thread about this topic: [what is the way to represent a unichar in lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780179/what-is-the-way-to-represent-a-unichar-in-lua) and the links provided in the answers, I am not fully understanding what I need to do in my final code that is acceptable for this to work.

I'm looking for some help in better understanding an approach that would help me to achieve my desired result provided below.

ETA:

Well I thought that I had fixed it with the following code:

```
function hexToAscii(input)
    local convString = ""
    for char in input:gmatch("(..)") do
        convString = convString..(string.char("0x"..char))
    end
    return convString
end
```

It appeared to work, but didnt think about characters above 127.  Rookie mistake.  Now I'm unsure how I can get the additional characters up to 256 display their ASCII values.

I did the following to check since I couldn't truly "see" them in the file.

```
function asciiSub(input)
    input = input:gsub(string.char(0x00), "<NUL>")  -- suggested by a coworker
    print(input)
end
```

I did a few `gsub` strings to substitute in other characters and my file comes back with the replacement strings.  But when I ran into characters in the extended ASCII table, it got all forgotten.

Can anyone assist me in understanding a fix or new approach to this problem?  As I've stated before, I read other topics on this and am still confused as to the best approach towards this issue.

Comment: additional characters up to 256 → there are much more than that in Unicode. And `%X` is the format for printing a number as hexadecimal. It indeed appears the bytes in your string are printed one by one as a hexadecimal number, eg **t** → `74`

Comment: @roeland You are correct in that my code will print out ASCII characters up to 127.  But beyond that, it is leaving me with no representation.  For example, if I wanted 234 in decimal ( or 0xEA ) I am not receiving the "omega" as I'd wish to receive.  Instead it is simply empty.

Comment: You also have to ensure that your ouput terminal interface (e.g., fonts) can handle the glyphs you desire to show.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do or what this has to do with Unicode. You seem to have a string that is a hexadecimal number, and you want to convert every 2 hex digits into a byte. That is not a Unicode-aware conversion. So where does Unicode fit in?

Comment: @NicolBolas you're correct.  Removed "Unicode" mentioning.  My string is comprised of pairs of hex digits which, ideally, I want to transition each pair into the ASCII representation.  Problem right now currently is going above 127 in Decimal.

Comment: Post-edit: [ASCII is a 7-bit encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Bit_width). By definition, you cannot have ASCII characters on the range 128-255. Now, your console (or whatever you use to display it) may interpret your text as a Windows codepage, UTF-8, Latin-1, or something else entirely. But as far as ASCII is concerned, it can't do anything outside of the 7-bit range. So unless you know what encoding to write, you can't get cross-platform output.

Comment: There is no _one_ "extended ASCII table," making the term pretty unless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple way to transform a base16-encoded string is just to

```
function unhex( input )
    return (input:gsub( "..", function(c)
        return string.char( tonumber( c, 16 ) )
    end))
end
```

This is basically what you have, just a bit cleaner.  (There's no need to say `"(..)"`, `".."` is enough – if you specify no captures, you'll automatically get the whole match. And while it might work if you write `string.char( "0x"..c )`, it's just evil – you concatenate lots of strings and then trigger the automatic conversion to numbers. Much better to just specify the base when explicitly converting.)

The resulting string should be exactly what went into the hex-dumper, no matter the encoding.

If you cannot correctly display the result, your viewer will also be unable to display the original input.  If you used different viewers for the original input and the resulting output (e.g. a text editor and a terminal), try writing the output to a file instead and looking at it with the same viewer you used for the original input, then the two should be exactly the same.

Getting viewers that assume different encodings (e.g. one of the "old" 8-bit code pages or one of the many versions of Unicode) to display the same thing will require conversion between different formats, which tends to be quite complicated or even impossible.  As you did not mention what encodings are involved (nor any other information like OS or programs used that might hint at the likely encodings), this could be just about anything, so it's impossible to say anything more specific on that.

Comment: Great information!  You gave me an idea where I will print out the hex representation (just the alphanumeric code) of each character I want for the time being until I know that the file is "correct".  I'll compare the files (copy of a file that is accepted by the slave) and the file I am trying to emulate to compare results with a hex editor.  Another Dumb Rookie Question: Although my master/host is not capable of populating the exact result I'd ideally wish to visually see, will the full output still be received and read?  Ex. 0xA5 -or- \xA5

Comment: @Pwrcdr87: `will the full output still be received and read?` Yes. Lua strings also double as Lua's way of dealing with arbitrary bytes of data.

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a couple of problems:

- First, make sure you know the meaning of the term character encoding, and that you know the difference between *characters* and *bytes*. A popular post on the topic is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)
- Then, what encoding was used for the bytes you just received? You need to know this, otherwise you don't know what byte 234 means. For example it could be ISO-8859-1, in which case it is U+00EA, the character **ê**.
- The characters 0 to 31 are control characters (eg. 0 is `NUL`). Use a lookup table for these.
- Then, displaying the characters on the terminal is the hard part. There is no platform-independent way to display **ê** on the terminal. It may well be impossible with the standard `print` function. If you can't figure this step out you can search for a question dealing specifically with how to *print* Unicode text from Lua.